# Get IFrame Url in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing facebook application using c# sdk ,I want to get the current facebook application visited by the user according to the url when i get the url using :

```
 UrlData = HttpContext.Current.Request
```

it gives me that url :

```
http://localhost:1365/
```

but i need to get the facebook application url from the browser :

```
http://apps.facebook.com/vastsverige/
```

any help or comments will be welcomed .

Answer (score 0):

on answer is to concatenate  the appId with the canavasurl in Facebook application settings within the facebook